# GLSL Editor and Debugger for MacOSX with ES2 support

Tags: shaders, ios, tools, glsl, macos

is there a GLSL editor for the mac? I need it for iOS OpenGLES2 shader.

How do you best debug shader?

Regards

Answer (score 5):

There are two supported GLSL editors for OS X. The first, known as Shader Builder, comes with the Graphics Tools available from the [Apple developer website](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/). The second is the open source [Shader Maker](http://cgvr.cs.uni-bremen.de/teaching/shader_maker/index.shtml). Neither of these tools are strictly for OpenGL ES 2.0, but the best workflow would probably be to get the look you want before you determine how to get the look you can have.

In terms of debugging shaders, it is very difficult to send debugging information back to the CPU. The only strategy that I have ever used is to use conditionals to output a specific color to the screen and look at the output. Tools such as [glslDevil](http://www.vis.uni-stuttgart.de/glsldevil/) also exist, but not for OS X.

Comment: If you do decide to use these tools and you are using a #version directive on your shader, be aware that you may need to comment it out during development if you get a shader compilation error due to the specific version not being supported.

Comment: all of them, except `glslDevil` - the one doesn't work on mac are outdated. the ui looks bad